# Kubernetes pods disappear after failed jobs

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am running Kubernetes jobs via cron. In some cases the jobs may fail and I want them to restart. I'm scheduling the jobs like this:

`kubectl run collector-60053 --schedule=30 10 * * * * --image=gcr.io/myimage/collector --restart=OnFailure --command node collector.js`

I'm having a problem where some of these jobs are running and failing but the associated pods are disappearing, so I have no way to look at the logs and they are not restarting.

For example:

```
$ kubectl get jobs | grep 60053
collector-60053-1546943400     1         0            1h
$ kubectl get pods -a | grep 60053
$    // nothing returned
```

This is on Google Cloud Platform running 1.10.9-gke.5

Any help would be much appreciated!

EDIT:

I discovered some more information. I have auto-scaling setup on my GCP cluster. I noticed that when the servers are removed the pods are also removed (and their meta data). Is that expected behavior? Unfortunately this gives me no easy way to look at the pod logs.

My theory is that as pods fail, the CrashLoopBackOff kicks in and eventually auto-scaling decides that the node is no longer needed (it doesn't see the pod as an active workload). At this point, the node goes away and so do the pods. I don't think this is expected behavior with Restart OnFailure but I basically witnessed this by watching it closely.

Comment: Try to investigate using the following commnads `kubectl get pods --selector=job-name=collector-60053 --output=jsonpath={.items..metadata.name})` to get pod name. Then, `kubectl logs <pod_name>`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

After digging much further into this issue, I have an understating of my situation. According to [issue 54870](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/54870) on the Kubernetes repository, there are some problems with jobs when set to `Restart=OnFailure`.

I have changed my configuration to use `Restart=Never` and to set a `backoffLimit` for the job. Even though restart is set to never, in my testing with restart never, Kubernetes will actually restart the pods up to the `backoffLimit` setting and keep the error pods around for inspection.

Comment: When the pods are restarted with `Restart=Never` do they maintain their same unique pod name? Or are they assigned a new unique pod name (refering to the last 5 randomly generated digits in the pod name and host name of the pod).

Comment: To answer my own question, when `Restart=Never` and `backoffLimit>1` then a separately named pod (different random 5 digit extension) will stay around for each failure, allowing you to go back and review each.

Answer (score -1):

Get the name of the job

```
kubectl get jobs --watch
```

Find the pod for that last scheduled job

```
pods=$(kubectl get pods --selector=job-name=nameofjob-xxxxx --output=jsonpath={.items..metadata.name})
```

Get pod logs

```
echo $pods
kubectl logs $pods
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I tried the selector approach and it still cannot find any pods. The pod seems to be hard deleted. Are there any other reasons a pod would be automatically cleaned up/deleted like that?

Comment: I see you posted a possible reason above. What happens if you disable auto-scaling but provision a higher number of nodes. Does issue persists?This could help in narrowing down the issue.